# In R use accumulate with nested conditions to set minimum and maximum

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, accumulate

I want to create a new column y that adds x to previous y value (i.e. lag(y)) and prints based on conditions below. The start value of y is 50.

1. If (x + lag(y)) is greater than 50, than print 50.
2. If (x + lag(y)) is between 0 and 50, then print x + lag(y).
3. If (x + lag(y)) is less than 0, than print 0.

I am tripped up on satisfying last condition. This is related to this question ([In R conditional statement with lag value and starting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654267/in-r-conditional-statement-with-lag-value-and-starting-value)).

**Reproducible data**

```
date<-seq(as.Date('1968-04-01'),as.Date('1968-09-01'), by='month')
 x<-c(20,10,-15,-50,11,-12)
 df<-data.frame(date,x)
```

**My code satisfying conditions 1 and 2, but not 3.**

```
df %>% 
mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~
if((.x + .y) > 50) 50 else .x + .y, .init = 50)[-1])
```

**Desired result**

```
y<-c(50, 50, 35, 0, 11, 0)
data.frame(date,x,y)
```

Comment: You can use `min()` and `max()` to put bounds on the return values so the function used in `accumulate()` would look like `~ max(min(.x + .y, 50), 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works when I add `.init = 50` to the end, resulting in `accumulate(vflux1,~ max(min(.x + .y, 50), 0), .init = 50)[-1] `.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a condition for the values below zero in your if statement. I did that as an *else if* in the middle of your code.

Therefore, the code should be:

```
library(tidyverse)

date<-seq(as.Date('1968-04-01'),as.Date('1968-09-01'), by='month')
x<-c(20,10,-15,-50,11,-12)
df<-data.frame(date,x)

df %>% 
mutate(y = accumulate(x, ~
if((.x + .y) > 50) 50 else if ((.x + .y) < 0) 0 else .x + .y, .init = 50)[-1])

data.frame(date,x,y)
```

If you have any questions, please write on the comments so I can adjust my reply or explain.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I apply this approach to my larger dataset I get an error in mutate caused by `if ((.x + .y) > 44169) ...`: ! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Comment: Do you have any "NA" in your dataset? If yes, we can add a condition to treat that.

Comment: Yes NA is present.